# Проблемы с направлением полёта пули

Tags: unity3d

Привет. Такая проблема: использую классический скрипт для стрельбы(физической), пуля вылетает из центра камеры. Но мне нужно, чтобы она вылетала левее/правее центра экрана, но направление у неё было в центр экрана. Чтобы понять, можно представить танк и стрельбу из пулемёта этого самого танка, при смене орудия прицел/вид не меняется, хотя пулемёт находится ниже, пули летят в центр(гравитацию можно убрать). Иерархия такая: Player->MainCamera(скрип который вращает эту камеру)->Объект, где спавнятся пули(там и скрип весит, который их спавнит) вариант с передвижением последнего объекта не подходит. В какую сторону смотреть вообще? Мучаться с вращением объекта или с физикой(направлением AddForce)?

Код пока такой:

```
GameObject BulletInstance = 
Instantiate(Bullet,gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
BulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 3125F);
```

Comment: Буквально парой вопросов ранее...  " 
Ну сделай так чтобы z ось проходила через дуло пистолета, сделай lookAt на точку. Точку заранее установи вдоль направления куда смотрит камера".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что возможности написать код нет, поэтому просто объясню принцип: при выстреле пускаете Raycast из камеры (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), получаете координаты RaycastHit и пускаете "пулю" в данную точку